# Kentia Palm drooping, browning, and tiny black spots

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, palm, kentia

We got a Kentia Palm about 5 months ago, and it was doing pretty well. We had it in a room with reasonably bright indirect light. And, we thought we were watering it appropriately only when the top inch of soil became dry. Over the last month, however, we noticed the leaves were starting to yellow and the branches were drooping significantly. I've noticed that the leaves and stems also now have little black dots all over them, and there are weird black things on the undersides of the leaves.

Other posts here and elsewhere online make me think this is some sort of mite or fungus infestation, but I'm not sure if it's a major issue or something we can overcome. Anyone know what might be going on here? Any help is great appreciated?

Photos (note these are from the garage, while trying to rescue the plant -- not its permanent home):

[image: Drooping leaves]

[image: Black spots on top of leaves]

[image: Under sides of leaves]